# ankh svn does not show in source control in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2012, ankhsvn

I installed TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN and restarted my PC. However, I can't find subversion link in **File -> Open** and AnkhSvn does not show up in source control in **Tools -> Options -> Source control**.
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN as well as Visual Studio 2012 with no success.

Can someone please help me with the integration of the SVN and Visual Studio 2012 Professional?

Comment: Do you see it in the list of installed extensions in **Visual Studio | Tools | Extensions and Updates**? Do you see it in **Visual Studio | Help | About Visual Studio**?

Comment: Thanks for Replying. But, I cant find ankh svn in extensions and updates or in help->about visual studio. what should i do further ?

Comment: @bahrep i reinstalled AnkhSVN and now i can see AnkhSVN in  Visual Studio | Tools | Extensions and Updates.. but still I cant find it in source control. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Since reinstall didn't help, i.e. you still don't see AnkhSVN as a source-control provider in Visual Studio, then it might indicate a bug or some problem with Visual Studio itself. I guess that you might get more help on this issue if you contact [AnkhSVN user discussions mailing list](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=582).

BTW, AnkhSVN does not rely or require TortoiseSVN client. Since you mentioned TortoiseSVN, then I suggest trying VisualSVN plug-in. If you are familiar with TortoiseSVN and like it then I'm pretty sure that you'll find VisualSVN very friendly and easy to use with practically no learning curve.

Comment: Thank you bahrep. I have put up a query in the link you provided and hoping for some positive response for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; the root cause is that registry is not correctly written during installation. Visual Studio Source Control Plug-In Selection drop-down list links to the registry directly.
My regedit had been disabled by system admin, so that the installing was failed (but you would not get any error message).
Re-installing AnkhSVN after enabling read/write permission of registry and the issue gets solved.

Comment: My colleague got the same issue, this time system admin helped to reset his Windows user profile (p.s., back up the needed data/config before resetting) and it worked like a charm.